# What 90's or 2000's movie has a monster wrap its pink tentacle around someone’s face?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I found the footage below in a video that contained clips from various tentacle-related films.

**Can anyone identify what film/TV series it's from?**

[image]

Comment: Is that image actually from the movie, or is it just similar to what you remember from the movie?

Comment: @Megafgk1 Have you looked through the checklists [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)? We have some good advice on writing ID questions, if you know where to look :-)

Comment: I sadly don't know more about it though. It is what I remember seeing.

Comment: @Megafgk1 how did you find this image?

Comment: I happen to see it on google. . . However, the website that it belongs to is NSFW. . . It was made in part of a tentacle video.

Comment: @Megafgk1: Ah. So you're certain this is an adult movie. That's important knowledge.

Comment: No, but it was used to make a video that was on a website with adult videos.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor thanks for the checklist, that will help out better when I make a question post.

Comment: Can you please post the link (with an NSFW warning, obviously). The image quality is very poor in the picture and we may be able to do better with the original video

Comment: Tremors? https://youtu.be/BAI8BM_XK2c?t=4m15s

Comment: @Valorum  Sorry to bother, did you make the gif?

Comment: @Megafgk1 - Patience is a virtue. While you wait. you can enjoy this joke -  **Q.** *How many tickles does it take to make an octopus laugh?* **A.** *Ten tickles*.

Comment: @Valorum I know that it Patience is a virtue. Also, funny joke there.

Comment: Looks like The Thing to me.

Comment: That looks very familiar - could it be a tongue and not tentacles? This is going to drive me crazy. 

I feel like I've seen this scene before and it may have been part of a sex scene or something.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles I thought about that a couple of time when I viewed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie is called New Nightmare. It is a Freddy Kruger movie, and in the one scene we see him wrapping the girls head with his tongue. You're welcome, took me a few tries to find this one.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't figure out that it was New Nightmare. Thanks for your help.